# How to create log file to errors

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller

I use pyinstaller3.1 to create a single executable file in windows.
If my code is wrong, will show

```
"Fatal Error! return -1".
```

What can I do, like Py2exe.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/StderrLog

If I user this methods like below, it creates "my_stderr.log" always.
I want to create the log file, only in executable file error.

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open("my_stderr.log",'w')
```

Comment: I use pyqt and i don't know what code will  raise exception, maybe is object has no attribute.
i don't know where should inside try-except block .
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Dialog()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Answer (score 0):

You can take your code inside try-except block and while caching exception you can open your file for writing log.

Comment: I use PYQT, but I don't know which code will raise exception. Maybe because I use the attribute that doesn't belong to the object. Where should I insert the try-except block？

Answer (score 0):

Use [user-defined-exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) to catch your own error

Else:
Simply write a log file using in `except` part  :

```
f = open("/path/to/file","a+") 
f.write("your message") 
f.close()
```

Comment: I use PYQT, but I don't know which code will raise exception. Maybe because I use the attribute that doesn't belong to the object. Where should I insert the try-except block？

Comment: if you do not know where the exception is raised, then use [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#module-pdb) to find the line number.